# Weird number after squaring the number from numpy matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I picked a number from Numpy matrix then squared it. The results looks weird.
In the code below, k should be 2.896e13; but what it spits is 377982976.
Seems it is a bug of Numpy. Is there any way to avoid this kind of bug?
Thank you for your help in advance!

```
i = np.matrix([0,0,5382000])
i[0,2]**2
out: 377982976
```

Comment: Looks like an overflow. Do you happen to have a 32 bit system?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Quang. Yes, I just modified it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

With the function `np.iinfo()`, it is possible to know the maximum positive value of a specific numpy type. As your result is bigger than the maximum value of `np.int32`, you need to use `np.int64` :

```
i_32 = np.iinfo(np.int32)
i_64 = np.iinfo(np.int64)
print(f"Max number for int32 : {i_32.max}")
print(f"Max number for int64 : {i_64.max}")
i = np.matrix([0,0,5382000], dtype=np.int64)
i[0,2]**2
```

```
Max number for int32 : 2147483647
Max number for int64 : 9223372036854775807

28965924000000
```